SAS proc sql: check for each value if value is in a list (with different list for each value)
Suppose that we have a group of people and all those people have a bag of clothes.
There is a table with for each person a record per item in their bag.
EX, Maria has a bag with a hat, some pants and shoes. Luka has a bag with pants, a shirt, socks and a sweater. John has a bag with socks and a hat. Kristen has a bag with earrings, shoes and a sweater.
Table: BAGS



Name
item




Maria
hat


Maria
pants


Maria
shoes


Luke
pants


Luke
shirt


Luke
socks


Luke
sweater


John
socks


John
hat


Kristen
earrings


Kristen
shoes


Kristen
sweater



Now suppose that there is another table with expected items.
EX Maria was supposed to bring a shirt and a hat. Luka was supposed to bring socks and a sweater. John is supposed to bring pants and Kirsten is supposed to bring shoes.
Table: Asked



Name
item
Brought




Maria
shirt
n


Maria
hat
y


Luke
socks
y


Luke
sweater
y


John
pants
n


Kristen
shoes
y



For every record in the asked table, I want to know wether this person has the item in the bag or not (see third column). So, check if the combination of the name and item in table 'ASKED' is included in the table 'NAMES'. I don't know how to do this, with a where statement it does not work because of the list to check is different depending on the name.
what I tried:
proc sql;
create table brought as (
select name
    , item
    , case when (name, item) in (select (name, item) from BAGS)
        then y
        else n end 
from ASKED
)
;quit;

This does not work, how can i do this kind of thing?

Why does the INPUT table ASKED already have the derived variable BROUGHT?  Isn't that the OUTPUT you want to create?  The INPUT would have just the first two columns.

Your syntax is invalid.  The IN operator can only work on ONE value.

I could identify some syntax issues, in your code -> this code should correct it:
proc sql;
create table brought as 
select a.name, 
       a.item, 
       case when b.name is not null and b.item is not null then 'y' else 'n' end as Brought
from Asked a
left join Bags b
on a.name = b.name and a.item = b.item
;quit;


Here is an SQL approach, since that is what you attempt.
data bags;
input Name $ item $;
datalines;
Maria   hat      
Maria   pants    
Maria   shoes    
Luke    pants    
Luke    shirt    
Luke    socks    
Luke    sweater  
John    socks    
John    hat      
Kristen earrings 
Kristen shoes    
Kristen sweater  
;

data asked;
input Name $ item $;
datalines;
Maria   shirt   
Maria   hat     
Luke    socks   
Luke    sweater 
John    pants   
Kristen shoes   
;


proc sql;
   create table brought as

   select a.*, ifc(b.item = '', 'n', 'y') as Brought

   from asked as a

   left join bags as b

   on  a.Name = b.Name
   and a.item = b.item

   order by Name desc
   ;
quit;


That is NOT how the IN operator works.  The syntax is VALUE IN (item1 item2 ....)  You cannot use something like (a,b) as the VALUE.
The most straight forward mapping of your attempt into SQL syntax is to use the EXISTS expression.
First let's convert your listings into actual datasets so we have something we can program against.
data bags;
  input Name :$10. item :$10.;
cards;
Maria hat
Maria pants
Maria shoes
Luke pants
Luke shirt
Luke socks
Luke sweater
John socks
John hat
Kristen earrings
Kristen shoes
Kristen sweater
;

data asked ;
  input Name :$10. item :$10.;
cards;
Maria shirt
Maria hat
Luke socks
Luke sweater
John pants
Kristen shoes
;

Here is an SQL query that works.
proc sql;
create table brought as 
  select a.*
       , case when (exists
      (select item from bags b where a.name=b.name and a.item=b.item)
              ) then 'y' else 'n' end as brought 
  from asked a
;
quit;

Results:
Obs    Name       item       brought

 1     Maria      shirt         n
 2     Maria      hat           y
 3     Luke       socks         y
 4     Luke       sweater       y
 5     John       pants         n
 6     Kristen    shoes         y

A more normal SAS way to do something like that would be to MERGE the two lists.  For some reason your original listings are not sorted so we will need to first sort the two datasets properly.
proc sort data=bags; by name item; run;
proc sort data=asked; by name item; run;

Now we can just merge the two by the NAME and ITEM and use the IN= dataset option to create flag variables to detect which datasets have contributed to the current observation.  We can use IN1 to detect when the item as asked for and IN2 to detect if the item was brought.
data want;
  merge asked(in=in1) bags(in=in2);
  by name item;
  if in1 ;
  brought = in2;
run;

Notice how I left BROUGHT as a numeric 1/0 variable instead of recoding it as a character y/n variable.  Binary 1/0 variables are usually much easier to deal with as you can use SUM() to count and MEAN() to find percentage.
